# Magento 2: How to override the core interface and add a new constant?

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin, extend, interface

I need to extend the core interface `Magento\NegotiableQuote\Api\Data\NegotiableQuoteInterface` and need to add a new constant but when I override the interface via preference its not working. When I read more about this I came to know that we can use extension attributes but not have clear information on this.
Please suggest me how can I add a new constant by overriding the interface.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The feature *Extension Attributes* is more designed for extend attributes for API.

You can define constant in any model or helper inside your custom extension.

You can see example in official documentation [Add extension attributes to entities](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/add-attributes/)

For add simple attribute to scalar entity:

- Add custom attribute into original table in `etc/db_schema.xml`
- Register your attribute in `etc/extension_attributes.xml`
- Create plugin for Repository to translate row field into extension attribute on get and back for save

If you have more specific requirements, please update your question or add comment.